# Inconsistent COUNT with DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

I have partitioned a table by the field `daynumber`. During the day I write into this table  logs and then calculate some stats. The table is big; each day I have ~3M new rows. The field `myField` is indexed.

This query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT myField) FROM mytable WHERE daynumber=somevalue;
```

returns 0, which is a mistake.

This query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(myField) FROM mytable WHERE daynumber=somevalue) t;
```

returns the correct value.

For some `daynumber` values, the first query works fine. I tried to repeir that partition but that had no effect. Any suggestions?

---

update

table scheme looks like

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `daynumber` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `myField` VARCHAR(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    ... other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (`daynumber`,`id`),
  KEY `myField` (`myField`(20))
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
PARTITION BY LIST (daynumber)
(PARTITION day_810 VALUES IN (810) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION day_811 VALUES IN (811) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION day_812 VALUES IN (812) ENGINE = MyISAM
....)
```

Answer (score 4):

this is because your `myfield` contains `NULL` value

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT coalesce(myField, '') )
FROM mytable WHERE daynumber=somevalue;
```

`coalesce` is sort of convert `NULL` to `''`
might not what your ask for, but will return the correct count (still)

Comment: +1. Nulls can do some funky stuff. My advice is to set fields to not-nullable if you plan to use them for cumulative totals, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Lets' say

- You match 4 rows for daynumber=somevalue
- MyField for these 3 rows are `1, 2, 2, NULL`

So, with the sub query there are 2 steps.

- `SELECT DISTINCT(myField)` gives 3 rows: `1, 2, NULL`
- `SELECT COUNT(*)` of this gives 3.

Without the subquery, one step

- `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(myField))` counts only `1, 2` = 2

Reason:

- `COUNT(*)` includes NULLs
- `COUNT(anythingelse)` doesn't count NULLs

The queries can't be inconsistent because they are *different queries*

The best discussion on it I can recall is on [DBA.SE: What is the difference between select count(*) and select count(any_non_null_col)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2511/630)

Comment: so, if "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT myField) FROM mytable WHERE daynumber=somevalue; " returns 0, that's mean that in table no non-null values? but i have non-null values

Comment: @antony: What does `SELECT DISTINCT(myField) FROM mytable WHERE daynumber=somevalue` give you?

Comment: @gbn: myField : (NULL)                   ,
352921025345134          ,
355970048645654          ,
357015047545097          ,
356046031045829          ,
354182027749272          ,
..and so on

Comment: @antony: and you say SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT myField) is giving zero? You need an add **exact** table design and data then. The queries you have posted should work: don't sanitise or clean them up.

Comment: @gbn: yes, i also think it should work, but it doesn't; thats why i posted this question :) i added table scheme into post

Comment: yes, the same in my queries in post; second query returns 72578; also, most of myField values is null. i cant understand why for some daynumber "select count distinct" returns 0, and for others - right results

Comment: @gbn let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2166/discussion-between-antony-and-gbn)